# Sencha Touch: Passing data from the 'listeners' to the detail view panel

Tags: sencha-touch, listeners

I am using the

```
  onItemDisclosure: function(record, btn, index) {...
```

but I require the whole list to be clicked, so now I am using the

```
  listeners: {
        itemtap: function (list, index, element, event) {...
```

to goto my detailed view.

BUT how would / could I pass the data that I have been passing using the 'onItemDisclosure' now using the 'listeners' method.

Current:

```
    onItemDisclosure: function(record, btn, index) {
        btToolbar.setTitle(record.data.title);
        detailPanel.update(record.data);
        App.viewport.setActiveItem(detailPanel, {type: 'slide', direction: 'left'});
    }
```

Proposed:

```
    listeners: {
        itemtap: function (list, index, element, event) {
            btToolbar.setTitle(??????????????);
            detailPanel.update(???????????????);
            App.viewport.setActiveItem(detailPanel, {type: 'slide', direction: 'left'});
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to retrieve the item from your data store using:

```
itemtap: function (list, index, element, event) {
   var record = store.getAt(index);
}
```

Comment: I have tried this but get an error, so I tried the 'this' so this.store.getAt(index); and it worked, thanks